# Writing to Google Play Leaderboard API callback returns successfully but no scores are recorded

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I've implemented Google Play Services into my Unity-Android game using the plugin [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity). All other aspects of the API work fine, I can unlock achievements, authenticate sign ins, bring up the leaderboard UI. However, when I request for a score to be submitted, the API callback is successful, as evidenced by my Debug.Log but I don't actually see any scores in the leaderboard.

Furthermore, when I look at the engagement section of my Google Play Dev console it confirms that scores were being submitted up until Feb 24 (the day we published the new APK and the linked game services).

This seems like it's more on Googles end than mine but Play Dev support seems to think otherwise. Has anybody had this problem before? I expected there might be some delay as Google Play takes awhile after everything is published for everything to be working as expected but it's been two days now and still no scores on the leaderboard. For sanity's sake the code I'm using to request the leaderboard report is

```
 Social.Active.ReportScore((long)score, string ID,(bool success)=>{});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The leaderboard score needs to be greater than the last one or it will not be changed, its an incremental leaderboard and you cannot decrease its value. (For each user/player)

Comment: Right, I kept that in mind but there are *no* scores on the leaderboard at all. Not even old ones, it's just empty

Comment: Ok i will check it tomorrow :) not at home